# Is it possible to combine AddressSanitizer and ThreadSanitizer into one build?

Tags: c++, gcc

Or do I have to use separate builds? The -fsanitize flag only allows for either address or thread but are multiple allowed?

Regards

Comment: Some multiples are allowed.  Not those two multiples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible to combine AddressSanitizer and ThreadSanitizer into one build (but other combinations are possible). You need multiple builds

> -fsanitize=address
>
> Enable AddressSanitizer, a fast memory error detector. Memory access instructions are instrumented to detect out-of-bounds and
> use-after-free bugs. The option enables
> -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope. See https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer for more
> details. The run-time behavior can be influenced using the
> ASAN_OPTIONS environment variable. When set to help=1, the available
> options are shown at startup of the instrumented program. See
> https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags#run-time-flags
> for a list of supported options. **The option cannot be combined with
> -fsanitize=thread or -fsanitize=hwaddress**. Note that the only target -fsanitize=hwaddress is currently supported on is AArch64.

> -fsanitize=thread
>
> Enable ThreadSanitizer, a fast data race detector. Memory access instructions are instrumented to detect data race bugs. See
> https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki#threadsanitizer for more
> details. The run-time behavior can be influenced using the
> TSAN_OPTIONS environment variable; see
> https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerFlags for a
> list of supported options. **The option cannot be combined with
> -fsanitize=address, -fsanitize=leak**.
>
> Note that sanitized atomic builtins cannot throw exceptions when operating on invalid memory addresses with non-call exceptions
> (-fnon-call-exceptions).

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html